# Python, BeautifulSoup or LXML - Parsing image URL's from HTML using CSS tags

Tags: python, image, parsing, beautifulsoup, lxml

I have searched high and low for a decent explanation of how BeautifulSoup or LXML work.  Granted, their documentation is great, but for someone like myself, a python/programming novice, it is difficult to decipher what I am looking for.

Anyways, as my first project, I am using Python to parse an RSS feed for post links - I have accomplished this with Feedparser.  My plan is to then scrape each posts' images.  For the life of me though, I can not figure out how to get either BeautifulSoup or LXML to do what I want!  I have spent hours reading through the documentation and googling to no avail, so I am here.  The following is a line from the Big Picture (my scrapee).

```
<div class="bpBoth"><a name="photo2"></a><img src="http://inapcache.boston.com/universal/site_graphics/blogs/bigpicture/shanghaifire_11_22/s02_25947507.jpg" class="bpImage" style="height:1393px;width:990px" /><br/><div onclick="this.style.display='none'" class="noimghide" style="margin-top:-1393px;height:1393px;width:990px"></div><div class="bpCaption"><div class="photoNum"><a href="#photo2">2</a></div>In this photo released by China's Xinhua news agency, spectators watch an apartment building on fire in the downtown area of Shanghai on Monday Nov. 15, 2010. (AP Photo/Xinhua) <a href="#photo2">#</a><div class="cf"></div></div></div>
```

So, according to my understanding of the documentation, I should be able to pass the following:

```
soup.find("a", { "class" : "bpImage" })
```

To find all instances with that css class.  Well, it doesn't return anything.  I'm sure I'm overlooking something trivial so I greatly appreciate your patience.

Thank you very much for your responses!

For future googlers, I'll include my feedparser code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

# RSS Feed Parser for the Big Picture Blog

# Import applicable libraries

import feedparser

#Import Feed for Parsing
d = feedparser.parse("http://feeds.boston.com/boston/bigpicture/index")

# Print feed name
print d['feed']['title']

# Determine number of posts and set range maximum
posts = len(d['entries'])

# Collect Post URLs
pointer = 0
while pointer < posts:
    e = d.entries[pointer]
    print e.link
    pointer = pointer + 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using lxml, you might do something like this:

```
import feedparser
import lxml.html as lh
import urllib2

#Import Feed for Parsing
d = feedparser.parse("http://feeds.boston.com/boston/bigpicture/index")

# Print feed name
print d['feed']['title']

# Determine number of posts and set range maximum
posts = len(d['entries'])

# Collect Post URLs
for post in d['entries']:
    link=post['link']
    print('Parsing {0}'.format(link))
    doc=lh.parse(urllib2.urlopen(link))
    imgs=doc.xpath('//img[@class="bpImage"]')
    for img in imgs:
        print(img.attrib['src'])
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you have posted looks for all `a` elements with the `bpImage` class. But your example has the `bpImage` class on the `img` element, not the `a`. You just need to do:

```
soup.find("img", { "class" : "bpImage" })
```

Comment: Haha.  Of course.  So that returns the url with tags.  Is there some way to strip those down to just the url?

Answer (score 1):

Using pyparsing to search for tags is fairly intuitive:

```
from pyparsing import makeHTMLTags, withAttribute

imgTag,notused = makeHTMLTags('img')

# only retrieve <img> tags with class='bpImage'
imgTag.setParseAction(withAttribute(**{'class':'bpImage'}))

for img in imgTag.searchString(html):
    print img.src
```